# WeightSum not working as expected in a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

Well, I have a LinearLayout with two children, an EditText and a Button and they both have a **weightSum** of **`3`**. All I want is to have a horizontal line with `2` layout_weight EditText and `1` layout_weight Button. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DBLocations"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But weights aren't working, here is the result:
[screenshot of the wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibshc.png)
What I have to do in order to have `2` layout_weight in EditText and `1` for the Button?

Comment: Both the widths must be **0dp**. And `weightSum` can be omitted.

Comment: My question shows scientific effort it is completely clear, useful and professional. Why you downvoted me? I already reported this.

Comment: Your question shows no effort in reading and understanding the official docs about weights.

Comment: You have right but it also needs to write in second line of code `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of wrap_content. It isn't working differently.

Comment: Then don't argue that weights don't work as **you** expect them to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your XML code .

And add `android:layout_width="0dp"` in your `Button` and `EditText` .

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal
    android:weightSum="3">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/DBLocations"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And also change the second line `android:layout_width` to be `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` right? :)
Now its working!Thanks.

Comment: Good luck to you !

Answer (score 0):

Make 'layout_width' as '0dp' for `Button` and set orientation for `LinearLayout` as `horizontal` as shown

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal 
    android:weightSum="3"> 

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit1" 
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="2"/> 

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/DBLocations" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think I can ommit the code for horizontal orientation as it is the default value, right?